# Division of result of two different queries into one

Tags: sql, count

I have two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM houses
WHERE with_people IS NOT NULL



SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM houses
where color = 'white' AND with_people IS NOT NULL
```

I do two queries and then I do (white_houses_with_people / white_houses) in my backend code.

Is there a way that I can do that division in SQL, so that I don't have to do two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'white' THEN 1 END) AS cnt2
FROM houses
WHERE with_people IS NOT NULL;
```

And ratio:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE((1.0*COUNT(CASE WHEN color = 'white' THEN 1 END)/NULLIF(COUNT(*),0)),0)  
AS ratio
FROM houses
WHERE with_people IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What happens if the denominator `COUNT(*)` is 0?

Comment: @HommerSmith Yes, just wrap everything with COALESCE

Comment: I don't fully understand why do you need both NULLIF and COALESCE

Comment: @HommerSmith First NULLIF() to handle 0 in division to avoid error, then COALESCE to change NULL to 0

Comment: @HommerSmith you could simply use `NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0)` and the entire result will be NULL instead of "division by zero".

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT 1.0 *
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM houses
    WHERE color = 'white' AND with_people IS NOT NULL) /
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM houses
    WHERE with_people IS NOT NULL)
```

The `1.0 *` is there to ensure that the result is `decimal(, 1)` instead of an `int`.